# Bootstrap Columns are not appearing side-by-side no matter what I try

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I have the following code:

```
                                <div class="mainptext">
                                    <h3><strong>Learn the following:</strong></h3>
                                    <div class="container">
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <div class="col-6">
                                                <ul>
                                                    <li>Lifts</li>
                                                    <li>False Deals</li>
                                                    <li>Side Slips</li>
                                                    <li>Passes</li>
                                                    <li>Palming</li>
                                                    <li>False Shuffles</li>
                                                </ul>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-6">
                                                <ul>
                                                    <li>False Cuts</li>
                                                    <li>Color Change</li>
                                                    <li>Crimps</li>
                                                    <li>Jogs</li>
                                                    <li>Peaks</li>
                                                    <li>Glides</li>
                                                    <li>Reverses</li>
                                                </ul>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
```

No matter what I do, the result is the second column appears directly below the other.

The Margin - 100% and it shouldn't be.

I used the following https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/grid/#equal-width for reference.

I've been doing web development for over 35 yrs and this, so very simple, is kicking me.

[image]

This code lives inside an article tag. It's not full width of the page but a piece of it.
**"NOTE: Ignore the DJ equipment. That picture will be replaced"**
[image]

Here's the section that holds the box:

```
            <!-- Main -->
            <div id="main" class="site-main container_12">

                <!-- Left column -->
                <div id="primary" class="grid_8">

                    <!-- About Us -->
                    <article class="single-post">
                        <header class="entry-header grad1">
                            <h1 id="equipTitle" class="entry-title">Welcome to our Magic Shop</h1>
                            <div class="clear"></div>
                        </header>

                        <div class="entry-content">
                            <br>

                            <!-- Magic Page 1 -->
                            <div id="magic1" class="entry-content-post equip-box-1">
                                <h3><strong>Card Magic Overview</strong></h3>

                                <p class="mainptext">Card manipulation is the branch of magic that deals with creating effects using sleight of hand techniques involving playing cards. Card manipulation is often used in magical performances, especially in close-up, parlor,
                                    and street magic. This is how I learned.</p>

                                <div class="mainptext">
                                    <h3><strong>Learn the following:</strong></h3>
                                    <div class="container">
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <div class="col-6">
                                                <ul>
                                                    <li>Lifts</li>
                                                    <li>False Deals</li>
                                                    <li>Side Slips</li>
                                                    <li>Passes</li>
                                                    <li>Palming</li>
                                                    <li>False Shuffles</li>
                                                </ul>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-6">
                                                <ul>
                                                    <li>False Cuts</li>
                                                    <li>Color Change</li>
                                                    <li>Crimps</li>
                                                    <li>Jogs</li>
                                                    <li>Peaks</li>
                                                    <li>Glides</li>
                                                    <li>Reverses</li>
                                                </ul>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <p class="mainptextnext">Click NEXT to continue...</p>

                                <div class="grid_4 margin-bottom slider-arrow arrow-box-1">
                                    <a class="prevslidee load-item" onclick="funcs.goLeft('magic1','magic0')">Prev</a>
                                    <a class="nextslidee load-item" onclick="funcs.goRight('magic1','magic2')">Next</a>
                                </div>

....
Thoughts?
```

UPDATE:  This is what I see in the DEV console
[image]
Then the console log:
[image]

Comment: Just tested your code in a snippit and it works fine with the CDN added to the snippit...

Comment: Well, that's not good.  What I'm getting will be shown in an UPDATE picture of the dev console.

Comment: Check out this fiddle copied and pasted verbatim https://jsfiddle.net/3pvg7y2c/

Comment: Maybe take a look at the computed style section of those elements in your dev tools and see if there is something weird with margin or padding? I think you may have something inheriting margin or padding down the DOM somehow... This would break the default behavior of the col classes from bootstrap.

Comment: try its     <div class="row align-items-center">  instead of   <div class="row">

Comment: Tushar, I tried your suggestion and it didn't work. Thank you. Dale, let me look into your suggestion further about computed style. I have to get to bed as I get up for work very early.  Thank you all. I'll report back tomorrow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just copy and paste your html elements and its working fine I using ***Bootstrap Version 4.1.3*** as CDN.

I think override style on columns so need to find which style is override from ***Inspect Element***.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="mainptext">
    <h3><strong>Learn the following:</strong></h3>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-6">
                <ul>
                    <li>Lifts</li>
                    <li>False Deals</li>
                    <li>Side Slips</li>
                    <li>Passes</li>
                    <li>Palming</li>
                    <li>False Shuffles</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="col-6">
                <ul>
                    <li>False Cuts</li>
                    <li>Color Change</li>
                    <li>Crimps</li>
                    <li>Jogs</li>
                    <li>Peaks</li>
                    <li>Glides</li>
                    <li>Reverses</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Raeesh, AWESOME man! Let me implement and get back to you in a bit. Just woke up. YOU ROCK and so does all others above because we are all helping each other.